# Python Crashes when Extracting Files Starting with “~$”

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I’m writing a python program that downloads a number of files and then searches their contents for certain keywords.  I’m using the zipfile module to search the contents of zip files as well.  The program usually works fine, but it has crashed when extracting files with filenames beginning with “~$”. When this happens I get the error message: “zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file.”

I manually opened one of these troublesome zip files in Windows Explorer.  The zip file and the document that caused the crash seemed unremarkable.  And from this vantage point the file didn’t have the odd characters in the filename.  Out of curiosity I removed and replaced the document in the zip file.  This time the file extracted without issue.  My program processed several more zip files until it encountered another filename beginning with “~$”and crashed with the same error message.

When I examined this second troublesome zip file in Windows Explorer the zip file and the document again seemed unremarkable, although this one did have a filename that began with “~$”.

Given that, is there any way I can safely extract files that for whatever reason have these weird file names?  If I only need to programmatically find and extract files from a zip file is there another new more robust library I could use?  I don’t have to worry about encrypted zip files.

Here is my code:

```
     with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip_ref:
        for file in zip_ref.namelist():
            file_extension = file[file.rfind('.'):]
            fileName = file[file.rfind('/')+1:]
            fullPath_to_extracted_file = f'{tempZipPath}\{file}'
            
             print(f'Zip member file: {fileName}')
               # Some omitted code here to skip over unsearchable files and items I’m not interested in.
                 zip_ref.extract(file, tempZipPath)
```

Comment: If it matters, I’m running Python 3.10.1 under Windows 10.

Comment: Files with names starting with "~$" are typically temporary files generated by Microsoft Office when a document is open. These files are hidden in Windows Explorer and are not meant to be accessed directly.

Comment: You should use `Pathlib` or `os.path.splitext()` to extract the filename and extension from a pathname, not string functions like `rfind()`.

Comment: @Maneesha Indrachapa,   Now that you mention it, I do recall seeing ~$ named back up files appearing while working with MS Office.   

Never the  less, someone thought these files were important enough to zip up and upload to our server.  They considered them content, not trash.  I'm assuming consumers of this data have been able to access and get some value from these items.  

If possible it would be nice to include them in my keyword search.

Comment: @BrianatWork: If Python says it’s not a zip file, it’s probably not a zip file. It’s also not unlikely that hidden temporary files were uploaded by accident.